# How to change Win + P monitor association

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I figure someone must have ran into this before.  I recently got a tri-monitor setup going and have two monitors in portrait mode to both sides of my main monitor.  Now short of switching what output I am using off my video card, is there any way to make one monitor considered "computer only" in the Windows Key + P screen?  I would like to be able to disconnect my flanking monitors with this, but it seems that my main display (set as primary) is always considered one of the extended monitors.